# SELECT * FROM tblXXX Returns Only One Result

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL 2008 R2 Express database that Im running an ASP.NET MVC 2 application on.

It always seems to be first thing in the morning when this problem arises - application login will fail. So I run a query against the database like `SELECT * FROM tblUser` and it returns only 1 result (always some random user and none of the others), making me think the records have been truncated.

So I try to recreate the admin user for example, which fails, and suddenly all users are back in the database (as reflected by a `SELECT * FROM tblUser` query)

Restarting the database service resolves the issue, but I need to find out why its happening. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: SQL Faeries?...You haven't given a great deal of information... hard to help without more info ...

Comment: You "run a query against the database like..." How like? Is it identical to what you've shown, or is there in fact more to the query?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - "like" in this instance meaning "for example" :) The query I ran this morning was exactly that one. I know there isnt much to go on here, but its all I have at the moment and Im really hoping someone else has at least experienced it before so that perhaps we can troubleshoot it?

Comment: I can't think of any likely explanations if this a) is genuinely a table, b) there's no parallel import occurring that you're not aware of, and c) you're not specifying any odd locking hints. I'd hope you'd rule out (b) for yourself, I'm guessing (a) is correct (although this wouldn't be the first time I encountered a view with a name like `tbl...`), and your query doesn't show any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I have a bad habit of simply copying my user instance databases and using them again in other projects that require a similar schema.

Knowing that, a friend of mine suggested scripting my entire database (including data, using SQL Management Studio) and recreating it from that.

Another friend suggested attaching the database to SQL Server 2008 full version, not Express, so I thought I'd combine the two ideas and script the database and data onto the SQL Server 2008 - which has worked :)

N.B. It also reminded me of how **blisteringly** fast SQL Server full version is!